# Confusion around the linearity of addition and scalar multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I know this seems like a very silly thing to be hung up on, but I'm having trouble understanding how to prove that vector addition and scalar multiplication are linear.  For simplicity's sake, let me refine my question in terms of vector addition.

The question is, how can I prove that vector addition is linear given the definition of a linear map?  Here's my attempt:

The rules for linearity are defined as:

1. additivity:  $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$
2. homogeneity: $\alpha f(a)=f(\alpha a)$

However, this is for a function of one argument.  The definition of a bilinear map is specified as:

1. additivity:  $f(a+c,b)=f(c,b)+f(a,b)$
2. additivity:  $f(a,b+c)=f(a,b)+f(a,c)$
3. homogeneity: $f(\alpha a,b)=\alpha f(a, b)$
4. homogeneity: $f(a,\alpha b)=\alpha f(a, b)$

I can easily prove that something like matrix multiplication is bilinear, and I can see that the equality does not hold when I attempt to use vector addition with the definition of a bilinear map.  It is straight forward for me to prove via substitution that vector addition is NOT bilinear, and matrix multiplication IS bilinear.  But what I'm having trouble understanding, is how to test a multiary function for linearity (not to be confused with bilinearity or multilinearity in general).

I know this sounds like I'm getting hung up on really minute detail, but I have written a math library in C++ and am working on an engine to rearrange expressions at compile-time to find the most computationally-efficient order of operations using operator properties.  In C++, operator+ takes two arguments and is therefore a binary function.  But is it possible that this is not true in a mathematical sense?  The rules for linearity seem to hold if I hold one of the arguments constant.  But why would it be the case that I can eliminate an argument with addition and not multiplication when doing this analysis?  Is there an argument to be made around degrees of freedom based on the definition of linearity or something that I'm missing?

Edit:
As suggested in the comments, I thought I'd provide some additional context for the types of optimizations I'm looking to implement.  I have a fully-vectorized library with GPU support that implements all kinds of kernels.  Some of these kernels are more efficient under certain circumstances than others.  I am using smart expression templates to build an expression tree, and a ton of template magic to rearrange the equations at compile-time based on efficiency.  Here are a couple of optimizations I'm looking to make:

1. Loop fusion.  Consider the case of $f(g(a,b),c)=a+b-c$.  I can compute all element-wise operations in a single loop and take advantage of SIMD vectorization.  This only works on element-wise operations with the same ABI, and obviously doesn't work out well if I throw an inner-product in the equation as in $f(g(a,b),c)=a*b-c$.
2. Cost minimization through associativity. Consider the case of $f(g(a,b),c)=a*b*c$.  The evaluation order matters greatly here, because the number of multiplications required to perform the operation can vary by orders of magnitude depending on associativity.  If a is a 1000x1000 matrix, b is a 1000x1000 matrix, and c is a 1000x1 matrix, then it is far faster to compute $f(a,g(b,c))=a*(b*c)$.  To do this, I need to tell the program the rules for associativity for each operation.
3. Differentiation can be made easier because of the fact that it is linear.  It is more computationally-efficient to multiply the scalar term into a vector prior to computing a jacobian than it is to multiply the scalar after computing the jacobian.  It is also useful for splitting up expressions due to the additivity property.  Automatic differentiation can also be setup according to properties such as this.

Anyway, there are obviously quite a few things that could/should be done algebraically to reduce the computational complexity.  My first step is to start taking a look at what properties each of these operators has and what the consequences of those properties are.  I realize linearity is not necessarily the property I need, as it's a composite property based on additivity and homogeneity.  Nevertheless, I'd like to try to step through the consequences myself and do some additional research before seeking recommendations on algorithms.

Comment: As you say, it seems bilinearity is not the concept you are looking for. FOllowing the argument, you should define the specific rules you wish to prioritize, and, maybe yes maybe not, bilinearity could have some role. I sense in here, some operators precedence should be of more importance for this problem, rather than specific mathematical concepts. But if those concepts match with what you need, great.

Comment: Having said that, could you include in your question which kind of expression rearranging are you wishing to do, so we could pinpoint onto the proper concept?

Comment: You have a mistake in your second "additivity" formula, perhaps a typo.  It is NOT "f(a, b+ c)= f(a,b)+ f(c, b)" as you have.  It is f(a, b+ c)= f(a, b)+ f(a, c).

Comment: You might also need to be a bit clearer about what you're considering as "vector addition" and "scalar multiplication" since we usually take linearity of addition and scalar multiplication as part of the definition of something *being* a vector space, so it naturally comes with the territory.

Comment: It's unclear what a proof of "linearity" has to do with rearranging expressions at compile time. And what specifically did you have in mind when you say you "can eliminate an argument with addition and not multiplication"? I wonder if we're looking at the real question.

Comment: @GeorgeIvey thanks, silly mistake on my end.  Good catch.  I've editted the question.

Comment: @DavidK If you assume addition has a single argument, then the addition is linear by additivity and homogeneity.  In other words, the operator is "addition over b", not "addition of a and b".  If you use "f(a,b)=a+b" as your operator, both linearity and bilinearity fail by definition.  If you use "f(a)=a+b" where b is just part of the definition of f, then linearity holds.  This is not the case for multiplication, where "f(a,b)=a*b" can be proven to be a bilinear map by substitution.  The question is really as simple as:  why?  addition HAS to be linear by definition.  It should be redundant.

Comment: @ConMan I mean it in the purest of mathematical sense.  I understand that scalar multiplication and vector addition are by definition, requirements for linearity.  That is why I am confused as to why I cannot substitute addition into the definition as a binary function and verify that is the case.  If I assume it to be a binary function, then the definition is somehow insufficient to describe this operator despite it being fundamental.  So what gives?  Is addition unary?  Is there an argument revolving around degrees of freedom since it is part of the definition of linearity?

Comment: Addition is one of the the binary operations (or maps, if you will) according to which we determine whether **other** maps are linear or bilinear. It clearly is not itself linear according to that definition. So what? A jury decides who is a criminal in a jury trial. Does that make juries criminals? ... You have a very interesting project there, and I would hate for you to get derailed by irrelevant philosophical questions.

Comment: @DavidK This won't hold my project up, but it would keep me awake at night to discover that we defined addition in such a way that addition itself is not additive.  Let me put it this way:  of all the math I've seen, this subtlety, if correct, would by FAR be the most surprising.

Comment: "Additive" [means something else in mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_function). Addition makes sums of things; it is commutative and associative, and multiplication distributes over it. Nobody said it was "linear" or "additive" and nobody needs it to be "linear" or "additive". We know what it does. While we try to build mathematical language up in a logical fashion, there are gaps. (There are logical gaps in ordinary language too: a french fry isn't French.) We do need mathematical language to communicate, but it's just words after all.

Comment: @DavidK I'm well-aware of what an additive map is, and I'm well aware that binary addition is something else.  And intuitively, I understand that "f(a)=a+b" is linear.  To conclude that "f(a,b)=a+b" is not additive absolutely breaks my brain after years of using superposition and never considering that the tools we define linearity with are considered nonlinear.  So, while I can appreciate your points (and obviously, I came to the same conclusion, hence the reason I asked the question), I still find them unsettling enough to not be confident in my own conclusion (which is the same as yours).

Comment: Generally, we use things we have already defined to define new things. Addition is something we defined first and then used to define linearity, so linearity is something "new" relative to addition. It would never have occurred to me to ask if addition is linear. It took me a while to even make sense of the question. So perhaps I am not the best person to resolve the mystery for you.

Comment: "If you assume addition has a single argument, then the addition is linear by additivity and homogeneity." No it is not, unless $b = 0$. If we define $f(a) = a + b$ then $f(a + c) = a + c + b$, while $f(a) + f(c) = a + c + 2b$. Similarly $f(ca) = ca + b$ while $cf(a) = ca + cb$. Neither condition of linearity holds when $b \ne 0$. This exactly the same reason $f(a,b) = a + b$ is not bi-linear. Note that in a vector space, only lines through the origin are subspaces. Other lines are not "linear". Instead we call them "affine". This is just the way the terminology developed.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I see your point. I agree that addition is nonlinear based on this discussion, which is surprising to me.

Comment: @PaulSinclair So my takeaway from this conversation, is that addition is not additive, and the equation of a line is nonlinear. f(x) = a\*x + b, so f(x+c) = a\*x+a\*c+b != f(x)+f(c) = a\*x+a\*c+2b